# Meteor Blaze.renderWithData(), how to pass functions

Tags: javascript, templates, meteor, meteor-blaze

I have a Template called dialog:

```
<template name="dialog">
    <div id='overlay' class='overlay'>
       {{title}}
       {{description}}
    </div>
</template>
```

and I render it on demand via the blaze function:

```
    Blaze.renderWithData(Template.dialog,{title:title,description:description,successfcnt:successfcnt,failfnct:failfnct},$("body")[0]);
```

This works as intended so far. But because its a modal dialog, I want to pass a successfunction and a failurefunction to the template.
I want to use these functions in one of the `Template.events({...somewhere here...})`. How can I access these functions or better call them?

Comment: what does `typeof this. successfcnt` logs?

Comment: That does the trick, thanks! You can just call the successfunction with `this.successfcnt();`. Easy as this, nice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `Blaze.renderWithData()` accessing the data context can be achieved by simply using `this`; so in your case I think `this.successfcnt();` should do the trick.